# Inequalities involving complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

a) Prove that $|z^i|< e^\pi$ for all complex $z \neq 0$.

b) Prove that there is no constant $M > 0$ such that $|\cos z| < M$ for all complex $z$.

Where complex powers are defined as $z^w=e^{w Log\  z}$ and complex cosine is $\cos z=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}2$.

Comment: What does $z^i$ mean?

Comment: $ z^i=e^{i (log|z| + i arg(z))}=e^{i log|z| - arg(z)} $

Comment: And what is $\operatorname{arg}(z)$?

Comment: $arg(z)$ it the angle $\theta$ of the polar coordinates of $z$ expressed in the interval $-\pi < \theta \leq \pi$. (I'm following "Mathematical Analysis" of Tom M. Apostol, 
being inexperienced with these topics I was not aware of the notation being not common).

Comment: The notation is common enough; the problem is how you normalize the argument, since it’s intrinsically not a well-defined function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question
you have that
$$
\left| w \right| = \left| {e^{ - \theta  + i\log \left| z \right|} } \right| = e^{ - \theta } \left| {e^{i\log \left| z \right|} } \right|
$$
but for any real $\alpha$ it is
$$
\left| {e^{i\alpha } } \right| = 1
$$
thus
$$
\left| w \right| = e^{ - \theta }  \leqslant e^\pi  
$$
For the second question I thin you mean $|\cos z|$ instead $\cos z$. In this case you  can use the Liouville Theorem: every entire bounded function is constant. Therefore, since $\cos z$ is entire and not constant it can not be bounded. In a more elementary way: if you choose $z=iy$ you have
$$
\left| {\cos iy} \right| = \frac{1}
{2}\left| {e^{ - y}  + e^y } \right|
$$ 
which of course is not bounded.

Answer (score 1):

a) Since you define $z^i$ as $e^{i\log\lvert z\rvert-\operatorname{arg}z}$, where $\operatorname{arg}z$ is the only argument of $z$ from $[-\pi,\pi)$, then$$\lvert z^i\rvert=\lvert e^{i\log\lvert z\rvert-\operatorname{arg}z}\rvert=e^{-\operatorname{arg}z}<e^\pi.$$
b) Use the fact that $\cos(iz)=\cosh z$.